# How to detect \n and then remove it?

Tags: c, newline

I've been working on a problem. I need to scan for a `\n` to end the cycle and delete it to not remain in a variable with other text. So far I have this:

```
do {                                    
    scanf("%[^\n]", userinput);            //loads stdin to char[] variable  
    end = userinput[0];                    //loads one char to char variable
    scanf("%*c");                          //should remove \n
    strcpy(inputstorage[i], userinput);    //copies userinput into 2d array of 
    i++;                                   //string with \n removed
} while (end != '\n');                     //should end cycle when I hit enter
```

What this does is, when I press enter it keeps the last char in the variable end.

For example I enter: '`Hello`'

In `userinput` is: '`Hello`'

In `end` is '`H`'

When I hit enter afterwards the end variable should contain \n but it contains '`H`' for some reason. I appreciate all the help you can provide

Comment: Consider using `fgets` instead. Will save you a lot of trouble.

Comment: Do you know that you have `'/n'` instead of `'\n'` in your loop condition?

Comment: Also, read your compiler warnings.

Comment: You fill `userinput` with non-newline characters, and then assign `end` to one of those characters, and then you expect `end=='\n'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`end = userinput[0];` saves the first character of input.  `scanf("%[^\n]", userinput);` does not put a `'\n'` in `userinput[]`, so testing if `end` is an end-of-line is not useful.

---

Use `fgets()` to read a line

```
char userinput[100];
if (fgets(userinput, sizeof userinput, stdin)) {
```

Then lop off the *potential* `'\n'` via [various means](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/2410359).

```
 size_t len = strlen(userinput);
 if (len > 0 && userinput[len-1] == '\n') userinput[--len] = '\0';
```

---

If code is obliged to use `scanf()`,

```
int count;
do {        
  char userinput[100];

  // Use a width limiter and record its conversion count : 1, 0, EOF
  // scanf("%[^\n]", userinput);
  count = scanf("%99[^\n]", userinput);

  // Consume the next character only if it is `'\n'`. 
  // scanf("%*c");
  scanf("%*1[\n]");

  // Only save data if a non-empty line was read
  if (count == 1) {
    strcpy(inputstorage[i], userinput);
    i++;
  } 
} while (count == 1);
// Input that begins with '\n' will have count == 0
```

---

A re-formed loop could use

```
char userinput[100];
int count;
while ((count = scanf("%99[^\n]", userinput)) == 1) {
  scanf("%*1[\n]");
  strcpy(inputstorage[i++], userinput);
}
scanf("%*1[\n]");
```

---

Note OP's code use `'/n'` in `while (end != '/n');`.  This is not the end of line character `'\n'` but a rarely used multi-character constant.  Certainly not what OP wanted.  It also implied that warnings were not fully enabled.  Save time enable all warnings. [@aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53063779/how-to-detect-n-and-then-remove-it/53065047#comment93026120_53063779).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. It works perfectly now. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use use scanf, [getline](http://http:/http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) or [fgets](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm) to get the line and then [strcspn](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcspn/) to remove the "\n".

eg. `userInfo[strcspn(userInfo, "\n")] = 0;`